# How do I create a 'inner glow ring' in Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would like to make a ring that has a faint inner glow ala this image:

[image]

I've tried first creating a circle, then applying a layer mask with a radial gradient from pure black to pure white, but that only achieves a linear gradient from center to edge, whereas this appears to be purely transparent right up to the edge of the circle.

Next I tried creating a circle again, then applying a inner glow effect. This nearly achieves what I want, except the circle is not transparent.

Here is my progress thus far:

[image]

Any tips? I am using Photoshop CS5. Would this be better done using different software?

Comment: Could you do things: 1. Add an image of what you've got so far. 2. Jot on the current image what you mean by "inner ring" ---- thinking you mean the white but not really sure

Comment: Sure. My progress thus far, with methods 1 and 2 http://imgur.com/wqfkkk7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay here's how I might approach it:

By playing with radial gradients with colors so we can see I got something like this:

[image]

Now I'm going back in and changing the blue for transparent, note how I pushed everything to one side:

[image]

Which gave this result:

[image]

Which isn't bad but not quite there yet. I redid the gradient pushed even further to the side. I also added a very small feather so there won't be a hard outside edge:

[image]

With the gradient pushed even further, and the feather added we get the following result:

[image]

Hope this helps you

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I've moved the transparent slider closer to the colour slider for a sharper shift in gradation, then played around with increasing gradation length to get it looking as desired. Is there anyway to ensure a perfect center gradation? I noticed you used guides but I was wondering if PS had something else that would help.

Comment: How would PS know what you want to center it around? Guidelines.